# Two-way SSL degrades performance as compared to one-way SSL

Tags: ssl, spring-security, https, tls1.2

I have created a Java application using Spring Security and I provided the `ssl.server` properties in `application.properties`. After enabling SSL handshake debug logs and verifying the connection I get a significant degrade in performance for two-way SSL.

Threads(users): 100
Request per thread: 100
1way SSL TPS: 110
2way SSL TPS: 25
noSSL (http): 120

Comparison between HTTP and one-way SSL is not that large as compared to one-way and two-way. I'm using Apache Tomcat.

I understand that there is an extra level of validation on server side. But is such a significant impact expected?

Comment: In 2-way SSL both the client and server do extra work during the handshake (the client signs something and server verifies the signature). After the handshake the workload is the same as for 1-way SSL. These must be very small HTTP payloads per connection.

Comment: Also the amount of data send by the client is larger since it must send the certificate.